# click function doesn't work for second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one problem with my code. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/vGKzPv)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are two edit button. When you click first edit button then the edit textarea will be on there. The problem is here if you click the blue cancel button and click again first edit button it is not working. What is the problem here? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html();
      var editMarkUp = '<div class="edBtnS"><div class="edSv">Save</div><div class="cNeD" id="'+ ID +'">Cancel</div></div><textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea>';
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
      var data = $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val();
       $('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus();
       $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(data + ' ');
   });
   $("body").on("click", ".cNeD", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = false;
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var currentMessageText = $("#txtmessage_" + ID).html();
        $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(currentMessageText);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
      <div class="postInfo">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsa
      </div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="1">Edit1</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
      <div class="postInfo">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsassss
      </div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="2">Edit2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `event.target` in `.cNeD` is not the same as in `.editBtn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Edit button is disabled with :

```
event.target.disabled = true;
```

You can add in the .cNeD click event :

```
$(".editBtn").prop('disabled', false);
```

[DEMO from codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VajRbj)

**Edit :**

To enable only one edit button (see u_mulder comment):

```
$(this).closest('.container').find(".editBtn").prop('disabled', false);
```

[DEMO from codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNZMVz)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is coming from `event.target.disabled = true;`
Try removing it, it worked for me.

Comment: It must  not be deleted because  it is important  for something  in devstud codes.

Comment: Thanks innovation, I was just trying around and noticed it was. @bugyt solution is proper.

Answer (score 2):

In your code for handling the cancel button click, you're setting the disabled attribute to false **for the cancel button**. As it is, this way of doing it is kind of ugly, and I couldn't get it to work. I did get it to work like this:

i.e.,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
// changed to disable event handler          
    $(this).off('click'); 
// rest of code
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".cNeD", function(event) {
// changed to re-enable event handler for the edit button in question
    $(this).siblings('.editBtn').on('click'); 
// rest of code
  });
});
```